# SharePoint | Web-Part | How to Limit Dropdown Options Based on the Status

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I'm wondering how to achieve this via custom web part and JavaScript

I'm looking for a way on how to limit the dropdown status based on its current state. For example I have status: Start, On-Going, Completed and Pending

the initial status of Start must only have On-Going as its option.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery - `$('#idofyourdropdown option[value="On-Going"]'');` OR

```
$('#idofyourdropdown option:contains("On-Going")');
```

OR using index asssuming On-Going is hte first option

```
$('#idofyourdropdown option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

OR even this

```
$('#idofyourdropdown').val('On-Going');
```

Comment: This actually helps me with the initial value. :)

How about limiting the status option? For example a status of "Pending" then I click "Ok" button. When I edit the item I should have "Pending, Completed, Rejected" as my only option "On-Going" should not be an option.